# create cascading dropdown in library of sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell how to create cascading drop down in the library of share point 2010 without the help of java script and info path designer.i am trying through java script techniques,but its not working properly and i don't want to use info path designer.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JavaScript and Infopath, you're into custom server side code. Without jQuery/Ajax then it's going to be a very clunky interface with multiple posts and screen redraws.

You may not be having much success with JavaScript but I can attest to using the SPServices and jQuery to achieve some very competent cascading dropdown solutions in SP207/2010 successfully. Have a look [Here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation), there's plenty of sample code and advice.

Comment: You can throw an update panel around those server side control to get rid of the screen redraws.  It isn't getting rid of the postbacks, but it does a good job of hiding them.

Answer (score 1):

I've had decent luck with using a 'custom field type' for such problems, if you need this to all be on an out of the box form.  If you don't need this to be on an out of the box form, then it's no different than any other ASP.NET cascading drop down.

I haven't used custom field types a lot, and I've found them a bit awkward to get started with, but they're not really all that complicated once you have the basic template as most of the information is static; you can just take an unrelated example from someone else and change the few bits that apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom form for the content type (if Visual Studio is an option) and do it like in any asp.net applications.

See here an example: http://spcustomforms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

spcascade.org provides best free solution which support multi level dropdown list with no limits.
It is javascript/jquery based solution with no page refreshes and involves only one look up list for multiple columns.
Saves data in single line text instead of Ids that are used by typical look up columns.
Very easy to use syntax too!

http://www.spcascade.org

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution without any JavaScript code: [Cascading Drop Down Lists in SharePoint](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint). Let me know if it solves your problem.